# VSTO Powerpoint Keep loading cursor on hold while uploading

Tags: c#, .net, cursor, vsto, powerpoint

I am developing addin for powerpoint which export and upload video to my server. While video is uploading, I want to show waiting cursor on PowerPoint. 
I have used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17618620/3209655) and this works fine. But if I use timer by this [logic code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535731/3209655), getting issue that the cursor changes back to default.

```
var vstoPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
vstoPresentation.CreateVideo("path\\to\\filename.mp4");

// Set cursor as hourglass
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((s, e) => {
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.vstoPresentation.CreateVideoStatus == PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusDone)
    {
        // Executing my time-intensive hashing code here...
        // uploading video to server

        // when upload finished
        // Set cursor as default arrow
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
});
aTimer.Interval = 5000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, crawling on many blogs and reading official documentation i found my solution.

```
var vstoPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;

//declare a variable to check if video is uploading
public bool videoUploading = false;

//we need to register a "BeforeClose" handler 
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.PresentationBeforeClose += new EApplication_PresentationBeforeCloseEventHandler(Application_PowerPointBeforeClose);
}

internal void upload(){
    vstoPresentation.CreateVideo("path\\to\\filename.mp4");

    // Set cursor as hourglass
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((s, e) => {
        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.vstoPresentation.CreateVideoStatus == PowerPoint.PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusDone)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.videoUploading = true;

            // Executing my time-intensive hashing code here...
            // uploading video to server

            // when upload finished
            // Set cursor as default arrow
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            Globals.ThisAddIn.videoUploading = false;
        }
    });
    aTimer.Interval = 5000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void Application_PowerPointBeforeClose(Presentation Pres, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.videoUploading == true)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Video upload is in progress, are you sure you want to abort?", "My Addin", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```